# Angle 59 degrees in Android gradient

Tags: android, gradient

I need to do gradient background in my android app. It's not a problem when we speak about 'angle' attribute is multiply on 45 degrees. But I need something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@color/gradStart"
    android:endColor="@color/gradEnd"
    android:angle="59"
    >
</gradient>
</shape>
```

What should I do to make it works? Is there any way to solve problems with a gradient?

Comment: It is **not** possible with [`GradienDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html). You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/skyfe79/AndroidGradientImageView) library.

Comment: @azizbekian Thanks you!

Comment: Have you resolved your question?